# Arduino Usb MIDI controller for Virtual DJ

Tags: arduino, midi

I have already build the controller, it is a simple rotary encoder with 4 segment display based on arduino micro. And now all i have left is to connect it to virtual dj using midi. im decided to use the "Serial MIDI Converter V2D" app to do it, but i cant understand how to write midi signals in arduino.

in code im using 4 effect names, by chosing one of them i can set the percentage 0-100 % it is int value. so how  can i send the midi signal to set that percentage for example to eq-high in virtual dj?

Comment: That converter is not USB. Anyway, did you read the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Midi)?

Answer (score 0):

In the VDJ mapper setup you can add a button by clicking de + sign, which will 'listen' for midi messages. The received Key you can attach to an action either by typing the command or command's in VDJ-script or by clicking Action-Learn and clicking the knob in the VDJ interface.